# detectar salto de linea archivo java

Tags: java, archivo

hola tengo este codigo que guarda los datos de un archivo de texto en un string y luego lo guarda en un vector de char y necesito detectar el salto de linea del string para poder guardarlo en otro vector char.
por ejemplo el dato del archivo de este codigo es :

```
NNNNNNNNBRAVBRRRRRAAAAAAAVVVVV

(N5)(A6)VBNNN(R6)
```

necesito guardar la primer parte en un vector de char y la parte de abajo en otro vector de char

les dejo el codigo que tengo hasta ahora:

```
package archivos1;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Archivos {

public static void main(String[] args) {

final String nomFich="datos.txt";

Scanner in = null;

try {

// abre el fichero

in = new Scanner(new FileReader(nomFich));

// configura el formato de números

in.useLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);



while (in.hasNext()) {

String palabra = in.next();


char[] vec=palabra.toCharArray();

for(int i=0; i<palabra.length();i++) {

    System.out.println(vec[i]);
}


} // while (in.hasNext())
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
System.out.println("Error abriendo el fichero "
+nomFich);
} finally {
if (in!=null){
in.close();
}
} // try
} // main


}
```

Comment: Ya probaste usando `in.nextLine()`?

Answer (score 0):

Usa la clase `BufferedReader` para poder usar el método `ReadLine`.

Acá te dejo un enlace directo a la documentación:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html

El método está disponible desde la versión 8 así que no creo que tengas problemas